# How strong is the Mon Calamari economy?

Tags: star-wars, the-mandalorian

During the Clone Wars they are a powerful ally to the Clone army. Later, in the Imperial era, they are the only group that can build large ships and have a remarkable fleet.

Didn't the Empire destroy their factories? Or at least didn't they use the factories for Imperial purposes?

And now, we see that the main character of *The Mandalorian* prefers a lower payment in Mon Calamari coin.

How could the Mon Calamari economy survive a war, an absolutist/fascist Empire and even second war and still be a reliable currency?

Edit: I'm looking for answers talking about Mon Calamari. 'The Mandalorian' reference was just a proof of how their currency is still a thing in the post-Imperial era.

Comment: I haven't seen _The Mandalorian_ yet so I am missing the context here but is the reason he accepts the lower payment solely down to it being a better currency or are there other reasons? For example, Watto doesn't accept Republic credits in the Outer Rim _and_ _The Mandalorian_ is set in the Outer Rim.

Comment: My point is not why he wold prefer mon-calamari coin against empire coin . It could be because he hate the empire, because it is not worth in where he lives, ... (those are just examples, not sppoiler, I really don't know why he refused the imperial coin). It is about how that currency is still reliable.

Comment: One reason could be that while the Empire has practically dissolved thus making Imperial credits worthless, the Mon Calamari still exist, so he can at least buy something or exchange them. Given his options, he took the one that minimizes the loss ;-)

Comment: @Rebel-Scum I'd post that as an answer. The Empire has fallen and its currency is no longer supported by the traders, but the Mon Calamari is still out there and its currency keeps his value.

Comment: Their economy LOOKS good, but if you dive below the surface it's a little fishy.  Personally, I think only suckers take their currency.

Comment: Mando didn't think it wise to accept payment in a currency for an essentially non-existent government. Although Greef states "it still spends" in relation to the Imperial credits, that doesn't guarantee that such will always be the case. Similar to US Confederate monies immediately following the US Civil War. It's possible the confederate cash might have still been useful in certain locations following the war for a short period but that did not last. Mon Cala is at least still a functioning government and economy

Comment: This scene doesn't really show that Calamari Flan was reliable. It was a slightly better alternative to the currency of the non-existent empire. It's like the choice between Soviet ruble and Venezuelan bolivar. The second is volatile, but at least it's recognized somewhere.

Comment: At least he could eat the Flan if he couldn't spend it